# Why UI is flickering on keyboard dismissal...?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I have created a runtime views as shown in Attachment, when user clicks on any Edittext then keyboard appears, after typing something I am making some operations in aftertextchanged callback. When I dismiss the Keyboard, there is a shifting of layout downwards as shown in attachment.I don't understand why the system is not able to render the UI immediately once the keyboard dismissal.Is that anything related to the AfterTextChanged() implementation.
Even tried by running the code in separate thread whatever i am executing in aftertextchanged but no use.
Please help me if anybody is having any idea.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

this might help you  decide wich mode meets your needs

try this one in your activity tag in the manifest

```
<activty windowSoftInputMode ="adjustUnspecified"/>
```

Comment: I tried all the possibilities of windowSoftInputMode but not working, here i am using Activity whose theme is dialog, is that causing the issue?

Comment: then try changing your window flag programmatically like : 

YOUR_WINDOW.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);